# MySQL workbench procedure returning no results

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Hello to the lovely stack overflow community. 
I have a set of values x values and I am trying to find the nearest larger value, then divide the difference by 2 and set this as a new value in new column called nearest_x. I have created a procedure with a while loop. The procedure runs and then give me no results. I think this is because I using the ele_id in the while loop, I think I need to simply look at each row in turn? Thoughts much appreciated. My first stack overflow post!

```
    DELIMITER ;; 
    CREATE PROCEDURE highX_rowperrow()
    BEGIN
    DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 0; 
    DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0; 
    SET n = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_csa WHERE condition = "pal0");

    SET i=0; 
    WHILE i<n DO #start while loop 
    SET @x1pal0 = (SELECT x FROM table_csa WHERE ele_id=(21001+i) AND condition = "pal0"); #count applicable rows (pal10 always first)


    SET @Xnearest = (select  x from table_csa  where    x > @x1pal0 and condition = "pal0" order by x asc limit 1); #Select the nearest larger than x value 

    SET @polypoint = @x1pal0+((abs(@x1pal)-abs(@Xnearest))/2); #calculate the difference and divide by 2 to set up point

    UPDATE table_csa SET nearest_x = @polypoint WHERE ele_id=(21001+i); #put value in table

    SET i=i+1; 
END WHILE;
```

END ;;

DELIMITER ;

So grateful for any help, I thought this would be a simple obvious answer and I missed something as I'm learning. I guess not so simple, so I'm adding more information to make it more of a re-producible problem. I have quite a big data set so not immediately obvious how to do that but here is my effort. I also tried to explain the background so it makes more sense.

I have a table which has the following columns:

- "ele_id" which is a set of location ids not necessarily individual in
  numbers, but does generally count up by 1.
- "x", which is x location,
- "y" which is y location,
- "condition" which is condition code for the location. So a different
  condition codes do exist for the same location later on in the data
  set.
- "nearest_x" which is the column I want to populate

I also added a snapshot with example data
[snapshot of table with example data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YvFn.png)

I am actually trying to turn these points into zones which I can make into a polygon, I have another data set in my database where I want to find which pieces of data fall within my polygons from the csa table. So I am trying to find the nearest x point value and calculate a point that falls half way between them, then I can do the same for y and draw a polygon. I know the condition pal0 has each location I need in it as an individual value which seemed like a good starting place.

As part of debugging I tried the following, this set of code performs what I want, but only on one element 21003 in this case, I can't seem to get it working in a while loop:

```
    Set @var=2;
    SET @x1pal0 = (SELECT x FROM table_csa WHERE ele_id=(21001+@var) AND condition = "pal0");
    SET @Xnearest = (select  x from table_csa  where    x > @x1pal0 and condition = "pal0" order by x asc limit 1);
    SET @polypoint =@x1pal0+abs(@x1pal0-@Xnearest)/2;
    Select @x1pal0, @Xnearest, @polypoint, ele_id from table_csa where ele_id=(21001+@var) and condition = "pal0" ;

    UPDATE table_csa SET nearest_x = @polypoint WHERE ele_id=(21001+@var);
```

Comment: are you getting any errors?

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/62576). Your question is more than *a very simple SQL query*, and it is more in need of that [mcve].

Comment: You could debug by putting select statements into the procedure..

Comment: Hi Darkonekt, I didn't get any errors, it ran and then said no rows changed.Thanks for the links Ken I will investigate.

Comment: I have found that I can do the function using very similar text on one of my elements below: but that this same solution isn't working in the loop. Why might this be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to use a cursor not a while loop!
[MySQL_tutorial_link]